# Calculating Land Surface Temperature using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

```
// Define the AOI
var nyeriCounty = ee.FeatureCollection('users/danielkamau20/Nyeri_county');
var aoi = nyeriCounty.geometry();

// Load Landsat 8 image collection
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')
  .filterBounds(aoi);

// Function to calculate LST
function calcLST(image) {
  var kelvin = image.select('B10').multiply(0.1);
  var emissivity = image.select('B11').multiply(0.001);
  var lst = kelvin.expression(
    '(Tb/(1 + (0.00115 * Tb / 1.438))*(((1/ emissivity) - 1)^(1/3.5)))',
    {
      'Tb': kelvin,
      'emissivity': emissivity
    });
  return image.addBands(lst.rename('LST')).copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
}

// Map the function over the collection
var lstCollection = collection.map(calcLST);

// Select LST band from the first image in the collection
var lstImage = ee.Image(lstCollection.first()).select('LST');

// Display the LST image
Map.addLayer(lstImage, {min: 273, max: 323, palette: ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow']}, 'LST');
```

This is the link to my code:https://code.earthengine.google.com/a9117e6e13f1e29be361aae13239c171

Error:

```
LST: Layer error: Collection.first: Error in map(ID=LC08_168060_20190116):
Image.bitwiseXor: Bitwise operands must be integer only.
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please take a [tour] to learn how the site works. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

`^` is bitwise xor operator. Since you use it instead of exponent in the expression, you get the error. Use `**` instead.

`... - 1)^(1/3.5)` ->  `... - 1)**(1/3.5)`

Comment: Is LST in Celsius degrees? You're providing a color scale for Kelvin degrees! Please check the code you write

Comment: The Lst in kelvin